# React component doesn't get event when action is dispatched from inside an ajax call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I try to dispatch an action from inside an ajax call, while the store itself gets updated (Checked in the browser redux plugin), the component doesn't receive the event, and therefore doesn't re-render.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  constuctor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.someAjaxCall();
  }
    someAjaxCall(){
        this.props.dispatch(someAction('Work'));
            $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "someURL",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            this.props.dispatch(someAction("Does Not Work"));

         }.bind(this)
  });
  }
  render(){
    return (<div></div>);
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (store, ownprops) => {
    return {
      store: store.get("Some_Key")
    }
  }


const render = (store,container) => {
   let ConnectedComponent = ReactRedux.connect(this.mapStateToProps)(SomeComponent);
      ReactDOM.render(
                <Provider store={ store }>
                  <ConnectedComponent/>
                </Provider>
        , container);
}

const someAction = (state) => {
  return {
    type: 'SOME_CASE',
    state: state
  }
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOME_CASE':{
      return state.set("stateKey",action.state);
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

From the above sample, when I call         this.props.dispatch(someAction('Work'));

The store gets updated, the component gets the event and re-renders itself. However, when I call from inside the 'success' function of an ajax call, the store gets updated, but the component never receives the event.

Comment: have you tried calling `this.someAjaxCall()` inside `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor` ?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. Did not work. Same behavior. The first dispatch works, but for the second one it only stores the value in the store and the component does not get called.

Comment: What event? do you expect `this.props.dispatch(someAction("Does Not Work"));` raise?

Comment: I expect after this.props.dispatch(someAction("Does Not Work")) the component to be rendered again because the state has changed.

Comment: what does your `action` and `reducer` looks like for your second dispatch?

Comment: I have added a sample action and reducer. I have also validated that the store is updated correctly for both dispatches.

Comment: In order to re-render the component you need to set the state. `this.setState({newstate});`. Re-render the component is not **responsability** of Redux, that's **React responsability**.

Comment: Your component won't re-render unless one its store-state mapped props changes, due to optimizations in ReactRedux.connect. In your example, that means that the value of store.get("Some_Key") needs to change. Are you sure it has changed in response to async action?

Answer (score 0):

If I am wrong, please correct me. 
The second Action creator call should not be failed as someAction is not global. Did you get any errors.